# android simulator file transfer speed

Tags: android, performance

I've installed the latest android sdk, and created an AVD, but the file transferring speed seems very low. when I try "adb push" "adb isntall" or debugging with ida/netbeans, the speed is at about **60k/s**

I found some tip from google that says when transferring files, click around with mouse. I tried this, the speed raised to **300k/s**, but I can't do the random clicking when debugging.

A friend has installed the same android sdk, (actually I copied all the sdk files from him).  His speed is about **2mb/s**, I don't know why.

Anyone knows this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Android emulator is notoriously slow and there are many threads on SO discussing it.  The only thing I found that really helps improve the performance of it is to enable Intel's Hardware Accelerated Execution Manager (HAXM) driver.  It makes the emulator run many, many times faster (including things like installing APK files via "adb install" like you are asking).

If you have an Intel CPU and don't mind using one of the x86 system images for your emulator, you should give it a try.  Here are the instructions:
http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/speeding-up-the-android-emulator-on-intel-architecture

Comment: Thanks, I tried the intel image, it runs with very high performance, and the file transferring speed is now 445k/s. I installed two apk, a helloworld.apk runs fine, but another one fails, it uses .so that compiled on ARM, I need to debug the .so in emulator. the DDMS shows:  
    Trying to load lib xxxxxx.so 0xb75d0640  
    Shutting down VM  
I guess the intel image doesn't support the apk that calls ARM .so?

Comment: For using native code you will need to build your .so for x86 also.  On that same instruction page linked above see the section "Compile Your NDK for x86".

Comment: Thanks, but it's a third-part .so, I don't have the source. Maybe I should use a real machine.